# Read char data from Arduino in C#

Tags: c#, arduino, serial-port

So I am developing a code where I am able to read data coming from an arduino through `SerialPort`. I already defined what characters I want to read from the Arduino  and depending on what to receive I will send something to the Arduino.

What I will receive is based on three characters: @, r and \r.

```
string arroba = "@" + "r" + "\r";
byte[] asciiBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(arroba);
```

I've mande this code but I don't know if this is actually gonna work.

When the arduino sent this to me I want to read it like :

```
comport.ReadByte(asciiBytes);
```

Could you help be figure out how I can read the data coming from the arduino like this?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should listen to incoming data by adding an event handler to your ComPort:

```
comport.DataReceived += Received;
```

Inside this handler, you can read the received bytes. Check this bytes if a specific sequence (@, r, \r) is in the received data:

```
private void Received(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    int bytes = comport.BytesToRead;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bytes];
    comport.Read(buffer, 0, bytes);
    if (buffer.Except(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("@r\r")).Any() == true)
    {
        //Your sequence was received
    }
}
```

Since `Except` is LINQ, don't forget to add

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: It is something like that, but I want to set in a case something like this: '@' + 'r' + '\r'. Together

Comment: I changed my answer @Forrobodo - hope this helps!

Comment: Every char will be one byte in the buffer.

Comment: It says "Cannot implicitly convert type 'char' to 'byte'"